# How do I make an instance use an encoding other than UTF-8

Tags: orbeon

I have an instance returned from an XML DB in iso-8859-1, Orbeon apparently does not like that and throws:

```
Fatal error: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
at org.orbeon.oxf.xml.XMLUtils$ErrorHandler.fatalError(XMLUtils.java:332)
at orbeon.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178)
at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:351)
at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:281)
at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1771)
at orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
at orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:845)
at orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:768)
at orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
at orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1201)
at org.orbeon.oxf.xml.XMLUtils.inputSourceToSAX(XMLUtils.java:418)
at org.orbeon.oxf.xml.XMLUtils.inputStreamToSAX(XMLUtils.java:403)
at org.orbeon.oxf.xml.TransformerUtils.readDom4j(TransformerUtils.java:357)
...
```

The character in question is valid iso-8859-1 ä (e4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default encoding for XML is UTF-8. If your service isn't using UTF-8, it needs to specify in the XML declaration what encoding is being used. For instance, if your data is encoded in ISO-8859-1, then the XML returned by the service should start with the following declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
```

Comment: ...and for those using xforms or xquery serialization, that can be done by using omit-xml-declaration to no or false (depending upon the xforms/xquery implementation chosen on the 'service' side) in submission/serialization options.  In fact, for xforms, the default is not to omit the declaration...Thanks Alessandro.